# Css: Bootstrap, importing only tables

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

How do I import only tables from the [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) framework?

**What I want to do:** I have found a couple of table examples from Bootstrap that I really like which I would like to import into my project.

**The issue:** When importing Bootstrap, in addition to tables, there are changes to other tags such as `h1`, `h2`, `title` and `html`.

**What I tried:** I got a **minimized**/**customized** Bootstrap that supposedly has only tables, but there are still changes to `h1`, `h2`, etc.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you share the code you tried to do so we can have some context?

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_tables.scss try change. An import other bootsrap modules. Look this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/#importing-styles

Answer (score 1):

normaly you should use the whole bootstrap package. There are great classes inside to make your whole page responsive.

If you only love the stilling of the tables maybe this snippet helps you:

https://gist.github.com/luisciphere/3c2d1710d90372784b072ebbcaf7bde4

Answer (score 1):

With bootstrap3 you were able to customize the package and just choose tables: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/

With bootstrap4 this option is gone. So I you basically have two choices:

- download the full package as unminified version and delete everything you don't need
- download the bootstrap sources (SASS) and only compile the table stuff

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I already did the customize one, that contains only Tables. Issue: Changes to h1,h2,html are still present.

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap 4, you will need to create a custom sass file and import the following bootstrap source files:

```
@import 'plugins/bootstrap/scss/_mixins';
@import 'plugins/bootstrap/scss/_tables';
```

This should enable you to make use of Twitter's table only.
For example:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: you may still have conflicts, but this all depends on how your CSS is structured.